# Please solve the derivative of an integration: ${\frac{d}{d x}}\int_{0}^{x^2}\sqrt{t^4+x^3}\,dt$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to get the value of

${\frac{d}{d x}}\int_{0}^{x^2}\sqrt{t^4+x^3}\,dt$

I am trying to let $F(x)=\int g(t,x)\,dt$ and get the difference, but $F(x^2)-F(0)=\int_{0}^{x^2}\sqrt{t^4+x^6}\,dt$, which is different from the original formula (since the thing to be integrated involves two variables: t and x, instead of only one variable).

Using partial derivatives, the original formula only becomes 
$\int_{0}^{x^2}\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{t^4+x^3}}\,dt$, I don't know how to integrate this.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Did you start by first applying the general form of the Leibniz' integral rule?

> $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\int_{g_1(y)}^{g_2(y)}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{g_1(y)}^{g_2(y)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx+g'_2(y)f(g_2(y),y)-g'_1(y)f(g_1(y),y)$$